# How to set the validation data for a concatenated deep CNN models?

Tags: validation, keras, concatenation, conv-neural-network

I have built a CNN model (keras-2.1.6) with two different structures, each with different set of input data. 
I am trying to use validation set in the model fitting. I couldn't get the valid dimension of "validation_data" since I have two different sets of data to be tested.

```
validation_data = ([tvar_test_data, mfcc_test_data], mfcc_test_labels)
```

With "tvar_test_data" and "mfcc_test_data" have equal dimensions of (40754, 12, 96) (samples, height, width)

The model:

```
branch_tvar = Sequential()
branch_tvar.add(Conv2D(kernel_size=8, strides=1, filters=6, padding='same',
                       input_shape=(n,m,1), activation='relu'))
branch_tvar.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
branch_tvar.add(Flatten())
branch_tvar.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
branch_tvar.add(Dropout(0.2))

branch_mfcc = Sequential()
branch_mfcc.add(Conv2D(kernel_size=16, strides=1, filters=5, padding='same',
                       input_shape=(n,m,1), activation='relu'))
branch_mfcc.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
branch_mfcc.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
branch_mfcc.add(Dropout(0.2))
branch_mfcc.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
branch_mfcc.add(Dropout(0.2))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Concatenate([branch_tvar, branch_mfcc]))
model.add(Dense(number_of_classes, activation='softmax'))
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.000384305959)
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = optimizer, metrics = ['accuracy'])
seed(2017)
model.fit([tvar_train_data, mfcc_train_data], tvar_train_labels, 
          batch_size = 128, nb_epoch = 10, verbose = 1, 
          validation_data=validation_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The labels dimension was not correct.

```
from keras.layers import concatenate 
from keras.layers import Dropout, Dense, Flatten, MaxPooling2D, Conv2D
from keras.models import Input, Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam

input_tvar = Input(shape=(n,m,1))
tvar_branch = Conv2D(kernel_size=8, strides=1, filters=6, padding='same',
                       activation='relu')(input_tvar)
tvar_branch = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, strides=2)(tvar_branch)
tvar_branch = Flatten()(tvar_branch)
tvar_branch = Dense(512, activation='relu')(tvar_branch)
tvar_branch = Dropout(0.2)(tvar_branch)

input_mfcc = Input(shape=(n,m,1))
mfcc_branch = Conv2D(kernel_size=16, strides=1, filters=5, padding='same',
                       activation='relu')(input_tvar)
mfcc_branch = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, strides=2)(mfcc_branch)
mfcc_branch = Dense(512, activation='relu')(tvar_branch)
mfcc_branch = Dropout(0.2)(mfcc_branch)
mfcc_branch = Dense(512, activation='relu')(tvar_branch)
mfcc_branch = Dropout(0.2)(mfcc_branch)

con = concatenate(inputs = [tvar_branch,mfcc_branch] ) # merge in metadata
tvar_mfcc = Dense(50)(con)
tvar_mfcc = Dropout(0.3)(tvar_mfcc)
output = Dense(number_of_classes, activation='relu')(tvar_mfcc)
tvar_mfcc_net = Model(inputs=[input_tvar, input_mfcc], outputs=output)
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.000384305959)
tvar_mfcc_net.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

#%%
seed(2017)
tvar_mfcc_net.fit([tvar_train_data, mfcc_train_data], tvar_train_labels, 
          batch_size = 128, epochs = 10, verbose = 1, 
          validation_data=validation_data)
```